# What is the meaning of "uniformly" in the limit of a function of two variables?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

Consider an arbitrary function of two variables $f \colon \mathbb N \times \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R$. My question is very simple: what does one mean by writing that

$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \, f(N,r) = 0 $$

uniformly in $r \in (0,R]$, where $R > 0$ is an arbitrary fixed constant ?

**My intuition.** Intuitively, I think that the condition I stated above is equivalent to saying that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a constant $L \in \mathbb N$ such that for every $N \in \mathbb N$ and $r \in (0,R]$ such that $N > L$, then it follows that $|f(N,r)| < \epsilon$ but I am not sure.

Can anyone confirm if I am right?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I'd say you're right.

Comment: "pointwise convergence" = "for each $r$ there is an $L$ such that ...". "uniform convergence" = "There is an $L$ such that for each $r$ ...". I.e. for uniform convergence, $L$ cannot depend on $r$.